# Starting with HiGHS

Tags: python, constraint, solver, highs

I have been messing about with HiGHS and trying to get a hang of its capability.

Here is an example of a simple model from their github repo
https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS/blob/master/examples/call_highs_from_python.py

In this example, adding variables and constraints is done through lp.col and lp.row respectively.

I'm getting a handle on how to do that, but here is another example from the repo
https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS/blob/master/examples/minimal.py#L8

where they use addVar and addConstr instead. This of course simpler and more straightforward. Anyway, when I try to replicate that addVar works and all the variables are added. On the other hand, addConstr results in an attribute error
***AttributeError: 'Highs' object has no attribute 'addConstr'***

I have been looking at the documentation with no luck to fix this issue. I have the latest version of the library. I'm wondering if this is something they haven't released yet maybe? I tried also to find the source code to see what function and attribute the model object has but couldn't find that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With version 1.5.3 you should add constraints using the `addRow(...)` method in the format `lhs <= constraint <= rhs`

```
m = highspy.Highs()
m.addRow(
  lhs,
  rhs,
  quantity of non-zero variables
  indexes of variables
  coefficients of the variables
)
```

For instance, if you have a knapscack constraint like $\sum_{i} w_{i} * x_{ij} <= c * y_{j}, \forall j$, then the code should be:

```
m = highspy.Highs()
for j in B:
  m.addRow(
    -highspy.kHighsInf,
    0,
    N+1,
    [idx_x[i,j] for i in range(N)]+[idx_y[j]],
    [w[i] for i in range(N)]+[-c]
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest release @ github is [1.6.0](https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS/releases/tag/v1.6.0)

The latest release available @ pypi is [1.5.3](https://pypi.org/project/highspy/).
This is the one you obtain when installing through `pip install highspy`.

While the feature you are trying to use was added (to some branch; see [MR](https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS/pull/1263)) in April 2023 and 1.5.3 was released in May 2023, **it seems it's NOT part of 1.5.3** as indicated in this [git-compare of the two releases](https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS/compare/v1.5.3...v1.6.0)

Well... at least it looks like it. Imho the git-history/branching looks kind of "wild". Your observation of having access to one function but not the other is strange but i think it's a result of [some overload](https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS/pull/1263#pullrequestreview-1391794732) (which looks a bit scary).